# Axios.all is returning an error

Tags: javascript, get, axios

I'm trying to run `axios.all()`, but I'm getting a strange error.

When using a `Promise`, it works just fine:

```
Promise.all([
  axios.get(`/conversation/api/totalCount/${Cookies.get('id')}`),
  axios.get('/api/all-members')
]).then(([totalCount, allMembers]) => {
  console.log('totalCount\n', totalCount) // I see the result
  console.log('allMembers\n', allMembers) // I see the result
})
```

But with `axios`, it's throwing an error right before the promise resolves:

```
axios.all([
  axios.get(`/conversation/api/totalCount/${Cookies.get('id')}`),
  axios.get('/api/all-members')
]).then(axios.spread((totalCount, allMembers)) => {
  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
  console.log('totalCount\n', totalCount)
  console.log('allMembers\n', allMembers)
})
```

The **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`** error is taking place right before the promise resolves (`.then()`).

I'm following [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/371) and the docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#example).  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  By the way, this is all client-side JS (could that be why it's not working?).

**How do I properly use `axios.all()`?**

Comment: Move one of the parentheses from before the `=>` to the end.

Comment: I sure would love to know who downvoted this question.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox!  That did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parenthesis is closed.It should be like this

```
axios.all([
    axios.get(`/conversation/api/totalCount/${Cookies.get('id')}`),
    axios.get('/api/all-members')
]).then(axios.spread((totalCount, allMembers) => { // I have removed a parenthesis here.
    // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    console.log('totalCount\n', totalCount)
    console.log('allMembers\n', allMembers)
})
```

Comment: Yes happens sometimes :)